# Filtering based on an attribute in deep level

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

Running Xquery on BaseX.

I want to filter based on an attribute in a deep level (/BLA1/BLA2/BLA3) but return attribute from both the filtering level and from one above it (/BLA1/BLA2).

So, as far as I understand, my "for" must run on the upper level (/BLA1/BLA2) in order to allow it. But I can't get the filtering to work.. when I try running the "for" on the deeper level - it does work but then I can't return the attribute I need from the upper level.

**This one works:** I get the required results as per the filtering.

```
for $i in /BLA1/BLA2/BLA3
where $i/@AT1>1000 and $i/@AT2='XX'
return $i/data(@AT3)
```

**This one doesn't work**, meaning the filter is not filtering and I get results in which $i/BLA3/@AT2 is NOT XX.

```
for $i in /BLA1/BLA2
where $i/BLA3/@AT1>1000 and $i/BLA3/@AT2='XX'
return $i/BLA3/data(@AT3)
```

I don't understand **WHY** the second one doesn't work...

**This is what I actually want to use**, i.e. return one attribute from the upper level (/BLA1/BLA2) and another attribute from the filtering level (/BLA1/BLA2/BLA3)

```
for $i in /BLA1/BLA2
where $i/BLA3/@AT1>1000 and $i/BLA3/@AT2='XX'
return $i/data(@AT4) || ' ' || $i/BLA3/data(@AT3)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `$i/../@AT4` certainly allows you to navigate up.

Comment: As for why things don't work, show us minimal but complete samples of input data, expected data and the two different results you get. Also tell us which BaseX version you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `..` to navigate up e.g.

```
for $i in /BLA1/BLA2/BLA3
where $i/@AT1>1000 and $i/@AT2='XX'
return $i/../data(@AT4) || ' ' || $i/data(@AT3)
```